# Why aren't there convenience functions for set_union, etc, which take container types instead of iterators?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, set, set-theory

std::set_union and its kin take two pairs of iterators for the sets to be operated on. That's great in that it's the most flexible thing to do. However they very easily could have made an additional convenience functions which would be more elegant for 80% of typical uses.

For instance:

```
template<typename ContainerType, typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator set_union( const ContainerType & container1, 
                const ContainerType & container2, 
                OutputIterator      & result      )
{
    return std::set_union( container1.begin(), container1.end(), 
                           container2.begin(), container2.end(), 
                           result );
}
```

would turn:

```
std::set_union( mathStudents.begin(), mathStudents.end(), 
                physicsStudents.begin(), physicsStudents.end(), 
                students.begin() );
```

into:

```
std::set_union( mathStudents, physicsStudents, students.begin() );
```

So:

- Are there convenience functions like this hiding somewhere that I just haven't found?
- If not, can anyone thing of a reason why it would be left out of STL?
- Is there perhaps a more full featured set library in boost? (I can't find one)

I can of course always put my implementations in a utility library somewhere, but it's hard to keep such things organized so that they're used across all projects, but not conglomerated improperly.

Comment: The same thing could be said about pretty much any STL-algorithm

Comment: Good point, but the question still stands. What's the philosophy behind not providing the most obvious convenience functions?

Comment: I think the idea is that algorithms can't modify containers.

Comment: If you are going to write your own then make sure they also work with standard array types. It would be a pain to have alter the code when I changed my type from an STL contain to a simple array and ended up with lots of compiler errors.

Comment: @Martin: That isn't a transparent change currently, so you wouldn't be worse off than you are now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are there convenience functions like this hiding somewhere that I just haven't found?

Not in the standard library.

> If not, can anyone thing of a reason why it would be left out of STL?

The general idea with algorithms is that they work with iterators, not containers. Containers can be modified, altered, and poked at; iterators cannot. Therefore, you know that, after executing an algorithm, it has not altered the container itself, only potentially the container's contents.

> Is there perhaps a more full featured set library in boost?

[Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/index.html) does this. Granted, Boost.Range does *more* than this. It's algorithms don't take "containers"; they take iterator ranges, which STL containers happen to satisfy the conditions for. They also have lazy evaluation, which can be nice for performance.

Comment: "it has not altered the container itself" then how do you explain how a `back_insert_iterator` works? I could agree if you said "it alters the container in a controlled fashion" or something like that.

Comment: @larsmans: The algorithm does not modify the container, the iterator does. The difference might seem menial, but there is a difference there. The STL cannot guarantee that you do not write functors that modify the container in strange ways and use those functors with the algorithms, but that does not mean that algorithms are broken because you can write such functors.

Answer (score 2):

One reason for working with iterators is of course that it is more general and works on ranges that are not containers, or just a part of a container.

Another reason is that the signatures would be mixed up. Many algorithms, like std::sort have more than one signature already:

```
sort(Begin, End);
sort(Begin, End, Compare);
```

Where the second one is for using a custom Compare when sorting on other than standard less-than.

If we now add a set of `sort` for containers, we get these new functions

```
sort(Container);
sort(Container, Compare);
```

Now we have the two signatures `sort(Begin, End)` and `sort(Container, Compare)` which both take two template parameters, and the compiler will have problems resolving the call.

If we change the name of one of the functions to resolve this (sort_range, sort_container?) it will not be as convenient anymore.

Comment: Thanks. This is more the sort of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, STL should take containers instead of iterators-pairs for the following reasons;

- Simpler code
- Algorithms could be overloaded for specified containers, ie, could use the map::find algorithm instead of std::find -> More general code
- A subrange could easily be wrapped into a container, as is done in boost::range

Comment: I don't think it should take them instead, but in addition. Having them take iterators is extremely flexible.

Comment: A `boost::range` is _not_ the same thing as a container. It is simply a pair of iterators. A container actually contains things; an iterator range is simply a sequence of elements. If you perform operations on a container, you can change the container itself (add/remove elements); if you perform operations on an iterator range, you _cannot_ change the container.

Comment: Catskul: but for the 1% of the cases you dont want to iterate over the whole container, you can do std::something(range(container.begin() + 5, container.end() - 3));

Answer (score 1):

@Bo Persson has pointed to a problem with ambiguity, and I think that's quite valid.

I think there's a historical reason that probably prevented that from ever really even being considered though.

The STL was introduced into C++ relatively late in the standardization process. Shortly after it was accepted, the committee voted against even considering any more new features for addition into C++98 (maybe even at the same meeting). By the time most people had wrapped their head around the existing STL to the point of recognizing how much convenience you could get from something like ranges instead of individual iterators, it was too late to even be considered.

Even if the committee was still considering new features, and somebody had written a proposals to allow passing containers instead of discrete iterators, and had dealt acceptably with the potential for ambiguity, I suspect the proposal would have been rejected. Many (especially the C-oriented people) saw the STL as a *huge* addition to the standard library anyway. I'm reasonably certain quite a few people would have considered it completely unacceptable to add (lots) more functions/overloads/specializations just to allowing passing one parameter in place of two.

Answer (score 0):

Using the begin & end elements for iteration allows one to use non-container types as inputs. For example:

```
ContainerType students[10];
vector<ContainerType> physicsStudents;
std::set_union(physicsStudents.begin(), physicsStudents.end(), 
               &students[0], &students[10], 
               physicsStudents.begin());
```

Since they are such simple implementations, I think it makes sense not to add them to the std library and allow authors to add their own. Especially given that they are templates, thus potentially increasing the lib size of the code and adding convenience functions across std would lead to code bloat.

Comment: -1: Yes, he knows that. He asked for a _convenience_ function; using `begin` and `end` is not very convenient.

Comment: +1 for pointing out arrays, but your example is wrong; it should be `students, students+9`, `end9)` should be `end()`.

Comment: I've heard this argument before, but why do you think it makes sense not to add it? Sure it's simple, but then again set_union is so simple, we could write that ourselves as well. The point to any of this is to that it doesn't *have* to be written by each developer down the line.

Comment: ContainerType was pulled from the OP, the rest was typo's/c++ learning :)